# Help finding the interior of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let $$S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|\,\,\, 0<x<1,\,\, y^2+z^2 \le1 \}$$

I know this might seem very simple but I don't understand the geometric representation of it my 3D graphing is really rusty right now. My guess is that the interior would be $$int(S)=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|\,\,\, 0<x<1,\,\, y^2+z^2 <1 \}$$

Is this the right way to approach it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your guess is right, now you have to prove it. Show that the set you found is the same as the set $\{x\in S| \exists \delta>0[B_{\delta}(x)\subseteq S\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not going to prove anything, but I’ll try to describe the region in such a way that you can sort it out.

Ignore $x$ for a moment: the equation $y^2+z^2=1$ gives you the unit circle in the $yz$-plane, so the inequality $y^2+z^2\le 1$ gives you the closed unit disk in the $yz$-plane. If you now allow $x$ to be arbitrary, you get the solid closed infinite cylinder of radius $1$ whose axis is the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^3$. You’re chopping that off at the planes $x=0$ and $x=1$, which are not included, so you’re getting the part of the cylinder lying strictly between those planes. The cylinder’s ends are not included, but the lateral (cylindrical) side is; it’s the only part of the solid that isn’t in the interior.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm only asked to find the interior not prove it. Even a picture would suffice and this helped a great load.

Comment: @User69127: You’re very welcome.